# Delivery Date for Opencart

Tags: php, datetime, opencart

I have a site on opencart, and I have this on step 4 (delivery method);

**Interlink Express 24 Courier**

- Interlink Express - Get it on: Wednesday, 13th of August

I already have a code, but it does not seem to work, on Saturdays it still seems to display Sunday as the delivery date.

```
<?php
// Text
$_['text_title'] = 'Interlink Express 24 Courier';

$datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
if ($datetime->format('l') == 'Sunday') $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow + 1 day');


$_['text_description'] = 'Interlink Express - Get it on: ' . $datetime->format('l, jS \of F ');
$_['text_weight'] = 'Weight:';
$_['text_insurance'] = 'Insured upto:';
$_['text_time'] = 'Estimated Time: Within 24 Hours'; 
?>
```

Also, is it possible to make it display the next date after a certain time (5:00pm) ?

So on a Monday at 5:01 it displays Wednesday instead of Tuesday.

Comment: Why do you create new DateTime objects in if statements, when you can just modify them? https://eval.in/178521

Comment: I'm quite a novice at PHP (and all code) so I'm not sure what you mean sorry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these two lines

```
$datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
if ($datetime->format('l') == 'Sunday') $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow + 1 day');
```

into these:

```
$now = new DateTime(); // uses actual date and time
if ($now->format('l') == 'Saturday') {
    // it is Saturday, delivery will be on Tuesday
    $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow + 2 day');
} elseif ($now->format('l') == 'Sunday' || in_array($now->format('l'), array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday')) && ((int) $now->format('H')) > 17) {
    // it is Sunday - delivery will be on Tuesday
    // or it is working day Mon..Wed after 5 p.m. - delivery will be on second working day
    $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow + 1 day');
} elseif (in_array($now->format('l'), array('Thursday', 'Friday')) && ((int) $now->format('H')) > 17) {
    // it is Thursday after 5 p.m. - delivery will be on next Monday
    // or it is Friday after 5 p.m. - delivery will be on next Tuesday
    $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow + 3 day');
} else {
    $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Hopefully it does, I have no way of checking it until Saturday haha!Many Thanks for your reply shady

Comment: Hey, I edited the code. Now it should check even whether it is Thursday or Friday after 5 p.m. and set the delivery on next second working day (previous code would promise delivery on Sunday if ordered on Friday after 5 p.m. :-)). Please notice, that this does not calculate with bank or other holidays that may occur during working week so it is always better to note this down in your *Terms & Conditions*.

Comment: BTW, how about orders placed on Friday before 5 p.m.? Will they be delivered during Saturday? If not, this has to be fixed as well...

Comment: Hey shady, We can deliver on Saturdays. Cheers

Comment: It works :) It displays the correct day (Friday) instead of Thursday